# Prove this vector identity using vector identities

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let $f$, $g$ and $h$ be any $C^{2}$ scalar functions. Using the standard identities of vector calculus, prove that;

$$ \nabla \cdot \left( f\nabla g \times \nabla h \right) = \nabla f \cdot \left(\nabla g \times \nabla h \right)$$

> Here is my working out so far; 
>   using identity 8 
>   $$ \nabla \cdot \left( f\nabla g \times \nabla h \right) = \nabla h \cdot \left(\nabla  \times f\nabla h \right) - f\nabla g \cdot \left( \nabla \cdot \nabla h \right)  $$ and the div of a scalar is a vector hence $$  = \overrightarrow H \cdot \left(\nabla  \times f\nabla \overrightarrow G \right) - f\nabla \overrightarrow G \cdot \left( \nabla \cdot \overrightarrow H \right) $$ and then using vector identity 10 gives me $$= \overrightarrow H \cdot \left(f\nabla  \times \overrightarrow G +\nabla f  \times \overrightarrow G\right) - f\nabla \overrightarrow G \cdot \left( \nabla \cdot \overrightarrow H \right) $$  and now I don't know whats next?

**Here are the vector identities listed below**

[image: Vector Identities]

Comment: @Daryl Hi Daryl, please see my updated post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT:** Use identity 7 with $\mathbf{F}=\nabla g\times\nabla h$.

Comment: The question is a lot easier than i thought, Thankyou

Answer (score 2):

HINT: Use Identity 8 with $\mathbf{F} = f\nabla g$, $\mathbf{G} = \nabla h$:
$$
\nabla \cdot (f\nabla g\times \nabla h)= \nabla h\cdot \big(\nabla \times (f\nabla g)\big)- f\nabla g\cdot \big(\nabla\times (\nabla h)\big).
$$
Notice $\nabla \times (\nabla h) = 0$. Then use Identity 10 on $\nabla \times (f\nabla g)$.

Comment: Hi Shuhao, that was exactly what I did before writing this question but I thought I was wrong because I couldn't make out anything of it after that. I have updated my post to show my attempt, and now I am unsure of what is next?

Comment: @amanda In the second term it is $\nabla \times (\nabla h)$, not $\nabla \cdot (\nabla h)$.

Comment: Ow, I see where I went wrong, thankyou for that Shuhao